# Mirror API static cards insert to GDK Activity

Tags: php, android, google-gdk, google-mirror-api

Is it possible to insert static cards using MIRROR API into my activity in GDK? I have an app using GDK that includes menus such as TAKE A PICTURE, RECORD A VIDEO and VIEW PATIENT DATA. I want my patient data to be populated with static cards using Mirror API. 
Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I ended up using CardBuilder in [Card Buildrer](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardBuilder) using a JSON response in HTTP request through my PHP file. It takes time to study for me but it actually better to use.